# Using parse_xml in an Ansible playbook

Tags: ansible, xml-parsing

I've been trying to parse XML data in Ansible. I can get it to work using the xml module but I think that using parse_xml would better suit my needs.

I don't seem to be able to match any of the data in the xml with my specs file.

Here is the xml data:

```xml
 <data xmlns=\"urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0\" xmlns:nc=\"urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0\">
  <ntp xmlns=\"http://cisco.com/ns/yang/Cisco-IOS-XR-ip-ntp-oper\">
   <nodes>
    <node>
     <node>0/0/CPU0</node>
     <associations>
      <is-ntp-enabled>true</is-ntp-enabled>
      <sys-leap>ntp-leap-no-warning</sys-leap>
      <peer-summary-info>
       <peer-info-common>
        <host-mode>ntp-mode-client</host-mode>
        <is-configured>true</is-configured>
        <address>10.1.1.1</address>
        <reachability>0</reachability>
       </peer-info-common>
       <time-since>-1</time-since>
      </peer-summary-info>
      <peer-summary-info>
       <peer-info-common>
        <host-mode>ntp-mode-client</host-mode>
        <is-configured>true</is-configured>
        <address>172.16.252.29</address>
        <reachability>255</reachability>
       </peer-info-common>
       <time-since>991</time-since>
      </peer-summary-info>
     </associations>
    </node>
   </nodes>
  </ntp>
 </data>
```

This is what the spec file looks like:

```yaml
---
vars:
  ntp_peers:
    address: "{{ item.address }}"
    reachability: "{{ item.reachability}}"
keys:
  result:
    value: "{{ ntp_peers }}"
    top: data/ntp/nodes/node/associations
    items:
      address: peer-summary-info/peer-info-common/address
      reachability: peer-summary-info/peer-info-common/reachability
```

and the task in the yaml file:

```yaml
  - name: parse ntp reply
    set_fact:
      parsed_ntp_data: "{{ NTP_STATUS.stdout | parse_xml('specs/iosxr_ntp.yaml') }}"
```

but the data does not return any results:

```
TASK [debug parsed_ntp_data] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [core-rtr01] => {
    "parsed_ntp_data": {
        "result": []
    }
}
ok: [dist-rtr01] => {
    "parsed_ntp_data": {
        "result": []
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I had never seen `parse_xml` before, so that was a fun adventure*

There appear to be two things conspiring against you: the `top:` key is evaluated *from the root Element*, and your XML (unlike the rest of the examples) uses XML namespaces (the `xmlns=` bit) which means your XPaths have to be encoded in the [`Element.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.findall) manner

For the first part, since `Element.findall` is run while sitting on the `<data>` Element, that means one cannot reference `data/...` in an XPath because that would be applicable to a structure `<data><data>`. I tried being sneaky by just making the XPath absolute `/data/...` but Python's XPath library throws up in that circumstance. So, at the very least your `top:` key needs to not start with `data` anything

Then, the `xmlns=` in your snippet stood out to me because that means those element's names are actually `NS+":"+localName` for every element, and thus an XPath of `ntp` does NOT match `ns0:ntp` because they're considered completely separate names (that being the point of the namespace, after all). It may very well be possible to use enough `//*[localname() = "ntp"]` silliness to avoid having to specify the namespace over and over, but I didn't try it

Again, as a concession to Python's XPath library, they encode the fully qualified name in an xpath as `{the-namespace}local-name` and there does not seem to be any way short of modifying `network.py` to pass in namespaces :-(

Thus, the "hello world" version that I used to confirm my theory:

```yaml
vars:
  ntp_peers:
    address: "{{ item.address }}"
keys:
  result:
    value: "{{ ntp_peers }}"
    top: '{http://cisco.com/ns/yang/Cisco-IOS-XR-ip-ntp-oper}ntp/{http://cisco.com/ns/yang/Cisco-IOS-XR-ip-ntp-oper}nodes/{http://cisco.com/ns/yang/Cisco-IOS-XR-ip-ntp-oper}node'
    items:
      address: '{http://cisco.com/ns/yang/Cisco-IOS-XR-ip-ntp-oper}node'
```

cheerfully produced

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": {
        "result": [
            {
                "address": "0/0/CPU0"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, the namespace was exactly the cause. think it would be wise for me to open a feature request?

Comment: I would suggest it, yes. If one were to work up the energy to interact with their repo, it'd be great to politely ask them to [stop swallowing `Exception`, too](https://github.com/ansible-collections/ansible.netcommon/blob/2.2.0/plugins/filter/network.py#L379) since it makes any debugging exercise that much harder

Comment: @mdaniel this time I won't submit my answer ;) It was a fun adventure for me too. Meanwhile, this filter really looks half-baked. I'll still give my "kinda working" scenario as an outside link: https://gist.github.com/zeitounator/8452c2a20860c0e924bd3ed9ff1af4e0